# Notes to be played together appear offset from each other

Tags: sheet-music

Are the highlighted groups of notes in the example below to be played together? My theory is that these groups of notes were drawn at a distance from each other in order not to clutter and create confusion.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your theory is correct: these notes are written offset from one another to be legible.  They are to be played simultaneously.

Answer (score -2):

Since hemidemisemiquavers are written as such, then the dots on a single stem should be played simultaneously. Otherwise it'll be a fast arpeggio, which is sort of what the hemidemisemis are.

Also why put an arpeggio sign when that's about the only way to play hemidemisemis.

Comment: @Tim "why put an arpeggio sign..." Because the arpeggio sign shows that *first* right hand note comes *after* the left hand note. (Or after all the left hand notes in the first chord, if there are more than one - it's hard to tell from the OP's image).